# proxy in class room java programming

Tags: java

There is a voice recorder which stores student voice as per roll number on which it was heard earlier. When the attendance process is complete, it will provide a list which would consist of the number of distinct voices. The teacher presents the list to you and asks for the roll numbers of students who were not present in class.

I'm trying to find out roll number of absent students in increasing order.

I wrote this case but some test cases are failing. I'm not sure what values would be in list which is provided by teacher.

There are only two inputs:

1. no of student
2. result from voice recorder

So can anyone tell what is missing here

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        ll.add(i);
    }

    String lines = br.readLine();
    String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        input.add(Integer.parseInt(strs[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {
        if (input.contains(ll.get(i))) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(ll.get(i));
        }
        if (i != ll.size() - 1) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you *maybe* format the code?

Comment: not able to edit

Comment: @LppEdd Formatted the code, waiting for peer review.

Comment: @govind Is the final if statement meant to be inside or outside of the else statement proceeding it? The lack of brackets makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @schwaitz inside else

Comment: @govind Answered below.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine and every test case passed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int stdCount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String rollNumbers = br.readLine();
    
    TreeSet<Integer> presentStudents = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    String[] rollNoArr = rollNumbers.split(" ");
    
    for(String s : rollNoArr) {
        presentStudents.add(Integer.valueOf(s.trim()));
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= stdCount; i++) {
        if(!presentStudents.contains(i)) {
            System.out.print(i);
            if(i < stdCount) System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm reading the question correctly, you first input the total number of students in the class. Each student has an assigned number, and you next provide a list of numbers (cooresponding to students present in class) seperated by spaces. Your code was missing a few brackets, which messed things up.

In addition, for this specific case, your logic of:

```
if (true) {
    continue;
}
else{
    // Do something
}
```

Can be made a lot simpler by doing:

```
if(!true){
    // Do something
}
```

Here is the final code that I touched up:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        ll.add(i);
    }

    String lines = br.readLine();
    String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        input.add(Integer.parseInt(strs[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) {
        if (!input.contains(ll.get(i))) {
            System.out.print(ll.get(i));

            if (i != ll.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An input of:

```
6
1 3 4
```

Results in an output of:

```
2 5 6
```

Comment: second input list is nothing but roll no , this test case is working for me also . but sheet provided by teacher would have different order  and i am taking just sequence till no of student , so my question of what would be more test cases in this case

Answer (score 0):

////working code using Java8

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<Integer> totalRolls;
    String[] inputRollsWithProxyStudentsRoll;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        totalRolls = IntStream
                .rangeClosed(1, Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        inputRollsWithProxyStudentsRoll = br.readLine().trim().split("\\s+");
    }

    List<Integer> rollsWithProxyStudentsRoll = Arrays
            .stream(inputRollsWithProxyStudentsRoll).map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    IntStream
            .range(0, totalRolls.size())
            .filter(i -> !rollsWithProxyStudentsRoll.contains(totalRolls.get(i)))
            .forEach(i -> {
                System.out.print(totalRolls.get(i));
                if (i != totalRolls.size() - 1) System.out.print(" ");
            });
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
          array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == array[j]) {
                    break;
                }
                if (j == n - 1 && i != array[j]) {
                    System.out.println(i + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```